# Mysterious blank button on my desktop

Tags: windows-10

some time, usually in correspondence of updates (Office, Windows etc.), appear and rest on top of everything a blank button for some time, I can move it but nothing more.
I scanned many times with antivirus but no matches.

here the picture:

[image: Strange Button Picture]

Some suggestions of what can be?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? It could be a simple visual glitch. Failing that, check Task Manager for any strange programs as it could be malware that isn't detected yet as it's a new definition.

Comment: If you go to your desktop, does it stay on top? Can you click it (seems like a button) can you drag it?

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to drag its bull's-eye on top of the button. This might find the process that causes it. Is it only in the browser, and what is your browser?

Comment: To answer to all comments:
- this is not one time things, this is a long time that i have and restarting of computer does´t affect
- This stay on top of every thing,Desktop, other programs, Browser and so on
- I can drag it, but doesn't do nothing on click
- I tried to check with Task Managed but nothing strange